# Svelte custom store lets us to modify the state directly

Tags: svelte, immutability, svelte-store

Below I have a custom store created in Svelte. First button `Add item` calls `addItem()` which will add new item to the state as expected. Clicking on the second button `Add item to object directly` updates the state too! How to stop this from happening and allow state modification only through `addItem()`?

**Steps to reproduce:**

- click on `Add item` button (we can see new the item render)
- click on `Add item to object directly` (we can see console error `Error: store.set is not a function` and we cannot see the item render)
- click on `Add item` button (now instead of **two** items we will see **three** items because previous click has directly modified the state)

```
<script>
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
    
    function itemStore() {
        const { subscribe, update } = writable({ items: [], name: 'test' });

        return {
            subscribe,
            addItem: () => update(n => ({ ...n, items: [...n.items, new Date().valueOf()] })),
        };
    }
    
    const store = itemStore()
</script>

<h1>The count is {$store.items.length}</h1>

{#each $store.items as i}
    <div>{i}</div>
{/each}

<button on:click={store.addItem}>Add item</button>
<br>
<button on:click={() => { $store.items = [...$store.items, new Date().valueOf()+' - added directly'] }}>Add item to object directly</button>
```

Comment: (I initially failed to mention that `Object.freeze` is not recursive and added a note regarding that to my answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operations like `$store.items = ...` first change the value, then trigger a store `set`, the setting of the store fails, but the object is still modified.

You could prevent this by freezing the object in the store, making it immutable.

```js
function itemStore() {
    const { subscribe, update } = writable(Object.freeze({
      items: [],
      name: 'test',
    }));

    return {
        subscribe,
        addItem: () => update(n => Object.freeze({
          ...n,
          items: [...n.items, new Date().valueOf()],
        })),
    };
}
```

(Note that `freeze` is not recursive, so if the array/individual items need to be frozen as well, additional code is necessary. The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#examples) give an example for a recursive implementation.)